# How to add a line with increasing numbers to a txt file using bash

Tags: bash, text-files, echo, sh

I want to add a line such as :

```
Var1 <- rbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6)
```

to a txt file. User will specify the numbers. If script is run as  `./script.bash 2 7`
text file should have the following line:

```
Var1 <- rbind(x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
beg=$1
last=$2
echo "Var1 <- rbind(???) " > output.txt
```

Is there an easy way to do this with bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something built around the `seq` command:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "var1 <- rbind(x"$(seq -s", x" $1 $2 )")" >> "output.txt"
```

`seq arg1 arg2` creates the sequence of numbers between `arg1` and `arg2` and the `-s` argument let us specify the delimiter string used.

The output of e.g. `seq -s ", x" 1 7` is `1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7` and we concatenate with the constant strings `var1 <- rbind(x` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=$1
last=$2
(
  echo -n "Var1 <- rbind("
  for n in $(seq "$first" $((last-1))); do
      echo -n "x$n, "
  done
  echo "$last)"
) >> "output.txt"
```

I am using a for loop to create the list of arguments (i.e. `xN`). The whole loop as well the other two statements that print the prefix and suffix of the line, are all run from within a subshell that is redirected to the file.

Comment: thanks a lot! your code is neat and easy for me to modify! it works very well

Comment: This would be both more portable and more succinct with `printf` instead of `echo -n`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends what you would describe as an *easy* way to do this but here's one option:

```
#!/bin/bash

beg=$1
end=$2

{
    printf 'Var1 <- rbind('
    for (( i = beg; i < end; ++i )); do 
        printf '%d, ' "$i"
    done
    printf '%d)\n' "$end"
} > output.txt
```

Loop through the numbers, adding the commas between. Redirect the output of the block to the file.